# hard lag when webcam is release

Tags: python, opencv, pygame, lag

I'm using the pygame and Opencv library to make a simple GUI with buttons and a webcam and whenever the webcam is turned off using the release() function from the OpenCv library, it lags the whole GUI out.

Here are the code snippet:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    # 3. here the interactions with the click of the mouse
    if b0.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()): 
        print("ON") # print text of button 1
            
    if b1.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        camera.release() # turns the webcam off 
        print("OFF") # prints text of button 2
```

Comment: Can you launch that part in a thread function? If it's an I/O block it would help.

Comment: [mre] is required. -- think about your code. do you need threads?

Answer (score 1):

You can release the camera in a thread:

```py
import threading
```

```py
def camera_release():
    camera.release()
release_thread = threading.Thread(target=camera_release)
```

```py
if b1.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
    release_thread.start()
    print("OFF")
```

Add a flag that indicates the recording status of the camera. Minimal example:

```py
import pygame
import cv2
import threading

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
success, camera_image = camera.read()
recording = True
def camera_release():
    camera.release()
release_thread = threading.Thread(target=camera_release)

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode(camera_image.shape[1::-1])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
off_text = font.render("recording off", True, (255, 255, 0))

run = success
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            recording = False
            release_thread.start()
    
    if recording:
        success, camera_image = camera.read()
        if success:
            camera_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(camera_image.tobytes(), camera_image.shape[1::-1], "BGR")
    window.blit(camera_surf, (0, 0))
    if not recording:
        window.blit(off_text, off_text.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```